# spring/spring-data: why not reference by type?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-cassandra

Recently we found that `spring-data`'s repository mechanism treats `cassandraTemplate` as a by-name reference (`RuntimeBeanReference`, more exactly).

It made me wonder that, "why not a by-type reference"?
Does `spring` provide runtime, by-type reference?
If so, are there some specific reasons for `spring-data` to make it this way?

I've tried search it but failed to found a relevant topic for that.

Comment: what about the case where you need two beans of same type ?

Comment: You convinced me with that. At first I was surprised that when only a `BeanMethod` with return type `CassandraTemplate` is present, _spring-data_'s repository failed to trigger that just because of a mismatching bean name...